# Set timezone as IST (+5:30) in DB Browser for SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have been searching for a setting in DB BRowser for SQLite on how to change the timezone to IST (Indian Standard Time +5:30) Is there a way to set it directly without running any queries? I also found some SQL queries that can convert the db time to IST but almost all are `SELECT` statements. I am looking for a setting to change the timezone permanently and if that is not possible then may be an update query which can read all records in the database and change/convert/replace all times to IST. Can someone shed some light on it?

My field name is "expire_time" set as `DATETIME` NOT NULL in `CREATE TABLE`

What I searched for was

```
INSERT INTO MyTable(MyColumn) VALUES(datetime(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'localtime'))
```

but I am not looking for insert statement

```
SELECT datetime(1092941466, 'unixepoch', 'localtime');
```

but I am not looking for select statement

Please help me either with a setting (if available in DB Browser for SQLite) or an update query that can change all times from GMT TO IST.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite has no DATETIME type. And it treats datatypes very different from other DBMS. For example

```
CREATE TABLE T (
   Field    MYTYPE
);
```

will run OK. Sqlite is applying so called datatype affinity https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity to figure out one of the implemented datatypes it will use instead of stuff specified it CREATE TABLE. DATETIME (as well as MYTYPE) affinity is NUMERIC - a special affinity which means column can store any type  you want, TEXT for example.

This boils down the only way to work with DATETIME in Sqlite is datetime functions. And those functions use default timezone UTC. Any other timezone must be provided explicitly as a part of the datetime string. No PRAGMA or something to change this default.

**EDIT**
If `expire_time` is currently a string expression of UTC time you can get specific timezone text value, for example

```
select datetime(expire_time, '+05 hours','+30 minutes') || ' IST' as t
```

Note `datetime(d,'utc')` will most probably return NULL if string `d` contains explicit timezone. So i advice you standardize on storing datetime as UTC in DB and convert it to different timezone needed only when generating an output. This way you have all Sqlite toolbelt at your disposal.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I went to modify the table and there was a DATETIME option to select. So what I understand from what you sent is that it does not treat as a pure datetime type and can hold any thing in it whether text or numbers. So if we need to replace those values with same values but adding 5 hours 30 minutes to it. Is it possible with an update query. If yes, can you please tell me the query syntax of updating (replacing existing values with values + 5:30)? Thanks... btw. I have updated my question with images.

Comment: i am sorry but i am not understanding this. i am a novoice and everything what i did so far is based on google search and research. i just want to convert the time shown in the pic above to local time so in first example, `2016-07-25 04:47:05.452000` should get converted as `2016-07-25 10:17:05.452000` and i wish to know how to convert this and replace old time with new time which would be +5:30. Thanks

Comment: To update the table this way run `update YOURTABLE set expire_time=datetime(expire_time, '+05 hours','+30 minutes')` . You was warned.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what i was looking for.